# How to fix "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'" in Python

Tags: python, list, int

I am working on a project, and I previously made a list called `salary` that works out someones salary based on their input. Now, I want to make a list called `'tSalaryExpenditure'` that will take the list `'salary'` and add up all the elements within the list. However, when I get to this stage I get an error saying

> "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'".

I am currently using the `'sum'` function, to find my way around the problem, I tried making a while, and various other loops.

```
salary = []
for i in range(len(tData)):
  tmpSalary = []
  warn = 0
    if total == 37.5:
      fullWeek = [a*b for a,b in zip(tmpRate,Hours)]
      tmpSalary.append(fullWeek)
    elif total > 37.5:
      fullWeek = [a*37.5 + ((b-37.5)*a)*1.5 for a,b in zip(tmpRate,Hours)]
      tmpSalary.append(fullWeek)
    elif total < 37.5:
      fullWeek = [a*b for a,b in zip(tmpRate,Hours)]
      warn += 1 
      tmpWarning.append(warn)
      tmpSalary.append(fullWeek)

  salary.append(tmpSalary)

tSalaryExpenditure = sum(salary)
```

Comment: Could you show a complete runnable example? Include a sample of `tData`, `total`, and any other missing variables.

Comment: Which line do you get the error?

Comment: What is the variable `total` on line 4?

Comment: Also fix up your indentation

Comment: Could you post your tmpRate, Hours values ?

Comment: I got the error on the last line - tSalaryExpenditure = sum(salary)

Comment: The variable total is the total number of hours worked each week per person

Comment: tmpRate is based on user input, and hours is the same as total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you use list comprehensions, the result is an array. So you have

```py
>>> fullWeek = [a*b for a,b in zip(tmpRate,Hours)]
>>> fullWeek
[450.0, 650.0, 700.0] # for example
```

So when you append `fullWeek` to another list it actually creates a list within a list.

```py
>>>[].append([450.0, 650.0, 700.0])
[[450.0, 650.0, 700]]
```

The problem is then doubled when you append `tmpSalary` to `salary`. So when you try to call `sum()` on that, it only sees the outer list object, and not the integers inside.

A way to fix that would be either to append single elements, or to specify the inner list to sum. Do **one of the following**.

```py
# Method 1
(...)
if total == 37.5:
      fullWeek = [a*b for a,b in zip(tmpRate,Hours)]
      tmpSalary += fullWeek
(...)

salary += tmpSalary


# Method 2
tSalaryExpenditure = sum(salary[0][0])
```